# Get a wav file from Google TTS API

Tags: text-to-speech, wav

a question concerning Google Text-to-Speech (TTS) with PHP.

With the help of this script http://stuffthatspins.com/stuff/php-TTS/

```
@$this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=".$lang."&q={$text}");
```

I have been able to access the Google TTS API and download mp3 files to my server. Unfortunately I don't get the mp32ogg programm installed on my server so I wanted to ask whether anybody knows if there is the option to download a .wav file directly from Google?
Just saving the resulting file as .wav didn't work as Firefox throws me a "couldn't decode this .wav file"

I would need it for Firefox support of HTML5 Audio.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your final goal is, but have you tried using the "embed" tag instead of "audio"?

I use Firefox and replacing:

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="<?=$mp3?>" type="audio/mp3" />
<source src="<?=$ogg?>" type="audio/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

with:

```
<embed src="<?=$mp3?>" type="audio/mp3">
```

got it working.

Let me know if it helps you out, I would like to see the finished project.